# jQuery Form: no va a ningun lado

Tags: javascript, laravel, formularios, crud

Estoy haciendo un formulario wizard, el código lo tomé de un admin template que obviamente no es mio y no tiene documentacion clara.

Lo he estado investigando y estoy seguro que el error esta en el js, debido a que no se en que lugar iria que si valida y tiene completa la info la envie a la url empresas.store para que la reciba el controlador.

No se mucho se JS y no entiendo como enviar la info una vez que se cumpla con las condiciones

Primero definí la ruta:

```
Route::resource('empresas', 'EmpresasController');
```

Posteriormente el controlador *EmpresasController* que se encarga de almacenarlo en la base de datos:

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    use App\Empresa;
    class EmpresasController extends Controller
    {
         public function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware('auth');
        }
        /**
         * Display a listing of the resource.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function index()
        {
            return view('admin.form');
        }

        /**
         * Show the form for creating a new resource.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function create()
        {
            //
        }

        /**
         * Store a newly created resource in storage.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function store(Request $request)
        {
            $request->validate([
                'nombreempresa'=>'required',
                'nombrecomercial'=>'required',
                'idfiscal'=>'required|max:13',
                'tel' => 'required|numeric',
                'calleynumero'=>'required',
                'colonia'=>'required',
                'ciudad'=>'required',
                'estado'=>'required',
                'codigopostal'=>'required',
                'pais'=>'required',
                'sector'=>'required',
                'serial'=>'required',
            ]);

            $empresa = new Empresa([
                'nombreempresa' => $request->get('nombreempresa'),
                'nombrecomercial' => $request->get('nombrecomercial'),
                'idfiscal' => $request->get('idfiscal'),
                'adminid' => auth()->id(),
                'tel' => $request->get('tel'),
                'calleynumero' => $request->get('calleynumero'),
                'colonia' => $request->get('colonia'),
                'ciudad' => $request->get('ciudad'),
                'estado' => $request->get('estado'),
                'codigopostal' => $request->get('codigopostal'),
                'pais' => $request->get('pais'),
                'email' => $request->get('email'),
                'acceso' => '1',
                'sector' => $request->get('sector'),
                'tipo' => '1',
                'sitioweb' => $request->get('sitioweb'),
                'serial' => 'XEVB-TBMN-KHKL-YB2JI89J',
                'wizard' => '1'
            ]);
            $empresa->save();
            return redirect('/dashboard')->with('success', 'Gracias hemos recibido tu informacion!');
        }

        /**
         * Display the specified resource.
         *
         * @param  int  $id
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function show($id)
        {
            //
        }

        /**
         * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
         *
         * @param  int  $id
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function edit($id)
        {
            //
        }

        /**
         * Update the specified resource in storage.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @param  int  $id
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function update(Request $request, $id)
        {
            //
        }

        /**
         * Remove the specified resource from storage.
         *
         * @param  int  $id
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function destroy($id)
        {
            //
        }
    }
```

y luego definí la vista que continiene el siguiente formulario:

```
<form id="kt_form" class="kt-form kt-form--fit kt-form--label-right" >
    @csrf
    <!--begin: Form Wizard Step 1-->
    <div class="kt-wizard-v2__content" data-ktwizard-type="step-content" data-ktwizard-state="current">
        <div class="kt-heading kt-heading--md">{{ __('forms.Account_Details') }}</div>
        <div class="kt-form__section kt-form__section--first">
            <div class="kt-wizard-v2__form">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-lg-7">
                        <label>{{ __('forms.Razon_Social') }}</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text"><i class="la la-registered"></i></span></div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombreempresa" placeholder="Enter full name">
                        </div>
                        <span class="form-text text-muted">{{ __('forms.Indication_RS') }}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-5">
                        <label class="">{{ __('forms.Nombre_Comercial') }}</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text"><i class="la la-bookmark"></i></span></div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombrecomercial" placeholder="Enter email">
                        </div>
                        <span class="form-text text-muted">{{ __('forms.Indication_NC') }}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label>{{ __('forms.Sectors') }}</label>
                        {!! Form::select('sector',$sectors,null,['class' => 'form-control', 'name' => 'sector','placeholder' => 'Selecciona', 'width' => '100']) !!}
                        <span class="form-text text-muted">{{ __('forms.Indication_Sector') }}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <label class="">{{ __('forms.Company_Site') }}</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text"><i class="la la-internet-explorer"></i></span></div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sitioweb" placeholder="Enter email">
                        </div>
                        <span class="form-text text-muted">{{ __('forms.Indication_CS') }}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <label>{{ __('forms.Rfc') }}</label>3
                    <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text"><i class="la la-user-secret"></i></span></div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="idfiscal">
                    </div>
                    <span class="form-text text-muted">{{ __('forms.Indication_Rfc') }}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <label>{{ __('forms.Phone') }}</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text"><i class="la la-phone"></i></span></div>
                    <input type="tel" id="kt_inputmask_3" class="form-control" name="tel">
                    </div>
                    <span class="form-text text-muted">{{ __('forms.Indication_Tel') }}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <label>{{ __('forms.Email') }}</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                     <div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text"><i class="la la-at"></i></span></div>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="john.wick@reeves.com">
                    </div>
                    <span class="form-text text-muted">{{ __('forms.Indication_Email') }}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--end: Form Wizard Step 1-->

    <!--begin: Form Wizard Step 2-->
    <div class="kt-wizard-v2__content" data-ktwizard-type="step-content">
        <div class="kt-heading kt-heading--md">{{ __('forms.Title_Ubic') }}</div>
        <div class="kt-form__section kt-form__section--first">
            <div class="kt-wizard-v2__form">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <label>{{ __('forms.Country') }}</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
                        {!! Form::select('country',$countries,null,['id'=>'country', 'class' => 'form-control kt-select2', 'name' => 'pais','placeholder' => 'Selecciona', 'width' => '100']) !!}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <label>{{ __('forms.State') }}</label>
                        <div class=" col-lg-4 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
                        {!! Form::select('state',['placeholder'=>'Selecciona'],null,['id'=>'state', 'name' => 'estado', 'class'=>'form-control kt-select2']) !!}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <label>{{ __('forms.City') }}</label>
                        <div class=" col-lg-4 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
                        {!! Form::select('town',['placeholder'=>'Selecciona'],null,['id'=>'town', 'name' => 'ciudad', 'class' => 'form-control kt-select2']) !!}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <label>{{ __('forms.Colony') }}</label>
                        <div class=" col-lg-4 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
                        {!! Form::select('colony',['placeholder'=>'Selecciona'],null,['id'=>'colony', 'name' => 'colonia', 'class' => 'form-control kt-select2']) !!}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-7">
                        <label>{{ __('forms.Calle') }}:</label>
                        <div class="kt-input-icon kt-input-icon--right">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="calleynumero" placeholder="Enter your address">
                            <span class="kt-input-icon__icon kt-input-icon__icon--right"><span><i class="la la-map-marker"></i></span></span>
                        </div>
                        <span class="form-text text-muted">{{ __('forms.Indication_Direcc') }}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                        <label>{{ __('forms.Postcode') }}</label>
                        <div class="kt-input-icon kt-input-icon--right">
                            {!! Form::text('postalcode', null, ['id'=>'postalcode','value'=>'', 'name' => 'codigopostal', 'class' => 'form-control', 'disabled' => 'disabled']) !!}
                            <span class="kt-input-icon__icon kt-input-icon__icon--right"><span><i class="la la-truck"></i></span></span>
                        </div>
                        <span class="form-text text-muted">{{ __('forms.Indication_Post') }}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <label>{{ __('forms.Tel') }}:</label>
                        <div class="kt-input-icon kt-input-icon--right">
                            <input type="text" id="kt_inputmask_3" name="tel2" class="form-control">
                            <span class="kt-input-icon__icon kt-input-icon__icon--right"><span><i class="la la-phone"></i></span></span>
                        </div>
                        <span class="form-text text-muted">{{ __('forms.Indication_Phone') }}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--end: Form Wizard Step 4-->
    <!--begin: Form Actions -->
    <div class="kt-form__actions">
        <div class="btn btn-secondary btn-md btn-tall btn-wide kt-font-bold kt-font-transform-u" data-ktwizard-type="action-prev">
            Previous
        </div>
        <div class="btn btn-success btn-md btn-tall btn-wide kt-font-bold kt-font-transform-u" data-ktwizard-type="action-submit">Submit</div>
        <div class="btn btn-brand btn-md btn-tall btn-wide kt-font-bold kt-font-transform-u" data-ktwizard-type="action-next">
            Next Step
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--end: Form Actions -->
</form>
```

Ahora, tengo el código js que se encarga de la validación de los pasos y que la información se encuentre completa para dejarlo que pase. Es aquí donde si el formulario esta correcto envie los datos a la ruta para que se almacenen pero no se especificamente donde indicarle la ruta:

```
"use strict";

// Class definition
var KTWizard2 = function () {
    // Base elements
    var wizardEl;
    var formEl;
    var validator;
    var wizard;

    // Private functions
    var initWizard = function () {
        // Initialize form wizard
        wizard = new KTWizard('kt_wizard_v2', {
            startStep: 1,
        });

        // Validation before going to next page
        wizard.on('beforeNext', function(wizardObj) {
            if (validator.form() !== true) {
                wizardObj.stop();  // don't go to the next step
            }
        })

        // Change event
        wizard.on('change', function(wizard) {
            KTUtil.scrollTop();
        });
    }

    var initValidation = function() {
        validator = formEl.validate({
            // Validate only visible fields
            ignore: ":hidden",

            // Validation rules
            rules: {
                //= Step 1
                nombreempresa: {
                    required: true
                },
                nombrecomercial: {
                    required: true
                },
                idfiscal: {
                    required: true
                },
                tel: {
                    required: true,
                    numeric: true
                },
                calleynumero: {
                    required: true
                },
                colonia: {
                    required: true
                },
                ciudad: {
                    required: true
                },
                estado: {
                    required: true
                },
                codigopostal: {
                    required: true
                },
                pais: {
                    required: true
                },
                sector: {
                    required: true
                },
                serial: {
                    required: true
                },

                //= Step 2

                //= Step 4

                //= Step 5
            },

            // Display error
            invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
                KTUtil.scrollTop();

                swal.fire({
                    "title": "ALTO",
                    "text": "Parece que te faltan algunos datos <br> here are some errors in your submission. Please correct them.",
                    "type": "error",
                    "confirmButtonClass": "btn btn-secondary"
                });
            },

            // Submit valid form
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                form.submit();
            }
        });
    }

    var initSubmit = function() {
        var btn = formEl.find('[data-ktwizard-type="action-submit"]');

        btn.on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            if (validator.form()) {
                // See: src\js\framework\base\app.js
                KTApp.progress(btn);
                //KTApp.block(formEl);

                // See: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxSubmit
                formEl.ajaxSubmit({
                    success: function() {
                        KTApp.unprogress(btn);
                        //KTApp.unblock(formEl);

                        swal.fire({
                            "title": "",
                            "text": "The application has been successfully submitted!",
                            "type": "success",
                            "confirmButtonClass": "btn btn-secondary"
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    return {
        // public functions
        init: function() {
            wizardEl = KTUtil.get('kt_wizard_v2');
            formEl = $('#kt_form');

            initWizard();
            initValidation();
            initSubmit();
        }
    };
}();

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    KTWizard2.init();
});
```

Comment: a tu etiqueta form no le falta el action? y el method?

Comment: No lo leí completo, es muy extenso, pero ... ¿ No tienes una pregunta con recompensa **exactamente igual** ?

Comment: como menciona el otro usuario, creo que te falta el action y el method , si vas al ejemplo de `http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxSubmit` que es el plugin que usa para el envío del formulario el form tiene esas propiedades, de lo contrario hay que especificarlas como opción :)